# How to Implement EJB with Web Application in Java With Eclipse IDE and Tomcat Server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ejb

I am working with Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers and Tomcat server 6.0.36. I want to develop EJB project with Java EE project. I have a project in IBM Web Sphere Studio Application developer 5.1.2 which has EJB implementation and deployed on IBM WAS server 5. I want to migrate this project on eclipse and Tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

Apache Tomcat is not a Java EE Container & doesn't support your Java EE project. But you can try Apache TomEE (which is a certified Java EE Container).

If your project is simple Java EE project, then there is no need for special migration tool. You can directly import the source into the Eclipse IDE.

Refer:

http://tomee.apache.org/tomee-and-eclipse.html

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lr8pxEACVRI